# Multiplying arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I've done some tests on multiplying matrices in python using the numpy library.

```
array1 = np.random.rand(100,100,100,100)
array2 = np.random.rand(100,100,100,100)

array_new1 = np.reshape(array1, (100*100, 100*100))
array_new2 = np.reshape(array2, (100*100, 100*100))

time1 = time.time()
product = array1 * array2
time2 = time.time()
time_tot1 = time2 - time1

time3 = time.time()
product2 = array_new1 * array_new2
time4 = time.time()
time_tot2 = time2 - time1

time5 = time.time()
prod_einsm = np.einsum('abcd, abcd->abcd', array1, array2)
time6 = time.time()
time_tot3 = time6 - time5

time7 = time.time()
prod_einsum2 = np.einsum('ab, ab-> ab', array_new1, array_new2)
time8 = time.time()
time_tot4 = time8 - time7

print time_tot1, time_tot2, time_tot3, time_tot4
```

In my real code, I'm working with higher dimensions and wondering how I might improve the performance. Undoubtedly, einsum is optimized well and works very fast. I also noticed the beneficial effect of using 2 dimension matrices instead 4. Is there anything else I could do? Maybe I should think of parallel programing? 
Any ideas and tips?

~

Comment: I don't think your `np.einsum` functions are equivalent to your elementwise-multiplication. It should be of the form `np.einsum('ij,ij->ij', a, b)`. Then at least on my machine, there is very little difference between using einsum or not for the array sizes here.

Comment: I just checked it out. I've corrected my code: np.einsum('ab, ab-> ab', array_new1, array_new2) and np.einsum('abcd, abcd->abcd', array1, array2). Looks like something is going wrong. Every time einsum works slower...

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it. Could you spell it out, please?

Comment: `einsum` can do this element multiplication, but it really is meant for more complicated combinations of dimensions, ones that don't express well with either `*` or `dot`.

Comment: I don't know what you're working on, but usually element-wise multiplication is not going to be the rate determining step of your program. While optimizing this certainly helps, if you are doing _anything_ else more sophisticated _at all_, e.g. calling some numpy linear algebra functions, then that will be far slower (and probably make calls to element-wise multiplication not in your control). You should profile your code for small-sized inputs and then try to speed up the slowest component.

Comment: For element wise operations, the number of dimensions has little effect on the speed.  It can ignore the dimensions, and just iterate over all elements as a flat list - and do so in compiled speeds.